# openEars project errors and warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, openears

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Warnings:
"`iOS deployment target '5.0' for architecture 'armv6' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '4.2.99' for the iOS 4.2 SDK.`
"

"`ld: warning: unexpected srelocation type 9`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured your project to deploy to iOS 5.0 but you are building against iOS 4.2 SDK.

Generally you do this the other way around: build against the latest SDK (say, 5.0) but set the deployment for the lowest version possible that you support (say, 4.2).